# Microsoft Azure CreateQueue using Simple REST Client

Tags: rest, azure, cloud

I'm trying to create a queue on Azure cloud. I've an Azure account, namespace and using Service Bus. Due to some restrictions I need to do it using RAW GET/PUT requests so I'm using [Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-rest-client/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

These are the values mentioned in REST client fields:

---

**URL**

https://mynamespace-ns.servicebus.windows.net/

**Method**

PUT

**Headers**

PUT /testqueue?timeout=30 HTTP/1.1

x-ms-date: Fri, 25 Sep 2015 03:16:12 GMT

x-ms-version: 2009-09-19

Authorization: SharedKey mynamespace-ns:oucfev8CXZPMsli4t7iZJ+nlC0fUwasyPH5OdSqi9po=

Host: mynamespace-ns.servicebus.windows.net

Content-Length: 0

---

This is how I'm generating the Authorization key:

HmacSha256 encoding the string "PUT\n\n\n\n0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Fri, 25 Sep 2015 03:16:12 GMT\nx-ms-version:2009-09-19\n/mynamespace-ns" with secret key is the SharedAccessKey copied from Connection Information page on Azure Portal. After that Base64Encode the resulted string.

Every-time I send the request I got the following response:

`401`MalformedToken: Invalid authorization header: The request is missing WRAP authorization credentials. TrackingId:8d52cae0-0dba-470d-8db2-3e76d4fd4d0b_G27,TimeStamp:9/25/2015 9:45:17 AM

Can anyone please tell what I'm missing or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The request has to have an access token attached in the request headers.  When using Azure service bus, you need to get a token from the azure access control service.  Found this page...

[Azure Access Token Patterns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rockyh/archive/2010/04/15/azure-access-control-service-client-patterns-part-1.aspx)

You do not need to use SDK to do all this as I am doing the same from an Android program.

EDIT...

You'll have to adjust this to whatever language you are using.

First get the token...

```
URL acsUrl = new URL("https://yournamespace-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/");
URL realm = new URL("http://yournamespace.servicebus.windows.net");
httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) acsUrl.openConnection();
httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
httpConn.setDoInput(true);
httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

String body = "wrap_name=" + URLEncoder.encode(AdminConstants.ISSUER, "UTF-8") + 
"&wrap_password=" + URLEncoder.encode(AdminConstants.ISSUER_SECRET, "UTF-8") +
"&wrap_scope=" + URLEncoder.encode(realm,  "UTF-8");
byte[] postBytes = body.getBytes();
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postBytes.length));
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

/* Fire the request here */

String[] responseProperties = response.toString().split("&");
String[] tokenProperty = responseProperties[0].split("=");
String token = URLDecoder.decode(tokenProperty[1], "UTF-8");
```

Your realm will be different since I am accessing service bus and you are creating queues.

Finally when you make your call to create the queue you will have to include the token in your post request like this...

```
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "WRAP access_token=\"" + getAcsToken() + "\"");
```

Comment: Thanks Dascalos for pointing it out. Now I know what is missing but as I'm working in raw GET/PUT requests, that .Net article doesn't seem to be very much helpful.

Comment: You don't need the SDK.  There are certain headers values that need to accompany the POST request.  The article above shows the header values you need.  I might be able to post something tonight that shows how I did it from Android.

Comment: Yes I did some search and found that POST headers can be used to get the token and that later I can use to perform an operation. But I didn't get the proper format for that token request.

I really appreciate if you can post how exactly you did it from Android. Meanwhile I'm gonna give it another try with some other modifications.